# Finitely many hyperplanes separating $ x,y $ in a CAT(0) cube complex

Tags: general-topology, geometry, discrete-geometry

I'm having a great difficulty understanding a proof of a lemma from this paper:

http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~erik/papers/cat0-A.pdf

It's lemma 1.12. To make it shorter for anyone who'd like to take a look: we are considering $ X $ - a $ \text{CAT(0)} $ cube complex. The set $ \mathfrak{H}(x,y) $ is a set of hyperplanes which separace vertices $ x,y $.

The moment I'm lost is the sentence: ,,since  $ \mathfrak{H}(x,y) $ is finite...''. I have no idea why it might / should be true.

I'd appreciate any form of  hint / explanation

Comment: The authors keep moving between $X$ as a geodesic metric space and its set of vertices with the restriction metric. I think at this stage they consider the latter. So the metric space is finite, and therefore there are finitely many ways to separate it with a hyperplane (the hyperplane being in the geometric space). This is just a plausible hypothesis regarding what they meant...

Comment: Yes, you are right. My problem was that I didn't understand quite well what those hyperplanes were supposed to be - it's not just a division of a complex into two path-connected subsets, but it's actually a hyperplane, orthogonal to its faces. Hence the set is finite